# PHP: how to 'cut' my array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
)
```

How can I remove the latest 2 cells and make it shorter ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't you mean the latest 3 cells?  Or is your example supposed to go up to index `3`?

Comment: some basic arithmetic here doesn't add up

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Check out [`array_slice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

So, if you wanted the first three elements only:

```
$array = array_slice($array, 0, 3);
```

If you wanted all but the last three elements:

```
$array = array_slice($array, 0, -3);
```

The second parameter is the start point (`0` means to start from the begining of the array).

The third parameter is the length of the resulting array.  From the documentation:

> If *`length`* is given and is positive, then the sequence will have that many
> elements in it. If *`length`* is given and is negative then the sequence will
> stop that many elements from the end of the array. If it is omitted, then
> the sequence will have everything from *`offset`* up until the end of the *`array`*.

Answer (score 8):

Slice it. With a knife.

Actually, with this:

```
array_slice($array, 0, -3);
```

Assuming you meant cutting off the last **3** elements.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php):

```
$new = array_splice($old, 0, 3);
```

The above line returns the first three elements of `$old`.

**Important:** `array_splice()` modifies the original array.

Comment: With `array_splice` you modify the array itself, so `$new === $old`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**array_splice**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) as:

```
$array = array(0,1,2,3,4,5);
array_splice($array,0,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.fyicenter.com/faq/php/php_array_function_6.php

Look at the one about truncating, particularly [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

Comment: These hints could have been posted as a comment under the question since this answer makes no attempt to implement specific resolving advice.   ...a typical problem for FGITW answers from 2010.