# Limit array to 5 items

Tags: php, arrays

I have a code that will add a number to an array each time a page is visited. the numbers are stored in a cookie and are retrieved later.

I would like to keep only the 5 most recent numbers in the array.

if the array is full (5 items) and a new number must be added, then the oldest number must be removed and the most recent items must be kept

here's what i have:

```
    $lastviewedarticles = array();

if (isset($_COOKIE["viewed_articles"]) ) {
  $lastviewedarticles = unserialize($_COOKIE["viewed_articles"]);
}

if (!in_array($articleid, $lastviewedarticles)){
    $lastviewedarticles[] = $articleid;
}
setcookie("viewed_articles", serialize($lastviewedarticles));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: how to 'cut' my array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585966/php-how-to-cut-my-array)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all i think, you need to obtain array length , then if length > or equal to 5, remove first element , and add element to the end of array.

```
if (!in_array($articleid, $lastviewedarticles)){
    $count = count($lastviewedarticles);
    if($count>=5)
        array_shift($lastviewedarticles);
    $lastviewedarticles[] = $articleid;
}
```

Answer (score 241):

[array_slice](http://php.net/array_slice) returns a slice of an array

```
array_slice($array, 0, 5) // return the first five elements
```

Comment: From the documentation: *If the array is shorter than the length, then only the available array elements will be present.*

Answer (score 11):

use array_splice and array_unique to get the 5 unique array values

```
array_splice(array_unique($lastviewedarticles), 0, 5);
```

Comment: This worked for me, but using array_slice rather than array_splice, so as per Nirav's answer with the array_unique finesse is what I'd recommend. So swerve the typo and this answer is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter to access the array, increment it in every call and use the modulus operation to write into the array. If your counter has to persist over several calls you have to store it in a session variable or a cookie.

Assuming that $i holds your counter variable this would look like

```
if (!in_array($articleid, $lastviewedarticles)){
   $lastviewedarticles[$i%5] = $articleid;
   $i++;
}
```

The result is a primitive ring buffer that will always contain the last 5 values.