# Getting array values before/after a certain value

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array of usernames:

```
Array
(
[0] => Sarah
[1] => Leon
[2] => Gary
[3] => Nathan
[4] => Adam
[5] => Lee
[6] => Alex
[7] => Andy
[8] => Terry
)
```

I would like to get the 3 users after a specific name, and the 3 users before a specific name. E.g. the 3 users after the name 'Adam' and the 3 users before the name 'Adam'

Does anyone know how this is achievable?

Comment: Google: `array_search()` + `array_slice()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: how to 'cut' my array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585966/php-how-to-cut-my-array)

Comment: You can use array_search function to find the key. After getting array key you can easily find array elements.

Answer (score 5):

Use [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
<?php

$names = [
'Sarah',
'Leon',
'Gary',
'Nathan',
'Adam',
'Lee',
'Alex',
'Andy',
'Terry',
];

$name = "Adam"; //name to be searched
$foundIndex = array_search($name, $names);

if (false !== $foundIndex) {
   $beforeNames = array_slice($names, $foundIndex -3 , 3);
   $afterNames = array_slice($names, $foundIndex + 1, 3);

   var_dump($beforeNames,$afterNames);
} else {
  // not found 
}
```

You can also check if the range is okay

Comment: Don't forget you need to take into account the possibility that the searched name isn't in the array `if {false !== $foundIndex} {/* slice here */}`.

Answer (score 1):

With [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) you get the key of the value you are looking for; then it's easy to build up a new array.

Answer (score 1):

use `array_search()` to get the key and then `array_slice()` to break..

```
<?php 
$input  = array(
                0 => 'Sarah',
                1 => 'Leon',
                2 => 'Gary',
                3 => 'Nathan',
                4 => 'Adam',
                5 => 'Lee',
                6 => 'Alex',
                7 => 'Andy',
                8 => 'Terry',
          );
$key = array_search('Adam',$input);       
$next = array_slice($input,$key+1,3);
$prev = array_slice($input,$key-3,3);

echo "<pre>"; print_r($next);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($prev);

?>
```

This will output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Lee
    [1] => Alex
    [2] => Andy
)

Array
(
    [0] => Leon
    [1] => Gary
    [2] => Nathan
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
<?php 

$temp = array('Sarah',
                'Leon',
                'Gary',
                'Nathan',
                'Adam',
                'Lee',
                'Alex',
                'Andy',
                'Terry');
$search = "Adam";

$index = array_search($search, $temp , TRUE);
if( $index ){
$dec = $index - 1;
$inc = $index + 1;
$max = sizeof($temp);
$c = 0;
$recs = 3;

//names before searched name
while( $c < 3 && $dec > 0 ){
echo $temp[$dec];
$dec--;
$c++;
}

//names after searched name
$c = 0;
while( $c < 3 && $inc < $max ){
echo $temp[$inc];
$inc++;
$c++;
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_array = array('Sarah', 'Leon', 'Gary', 'Adam');

$key = key( preg_grep( '/Adam/' , $my_array ) );


// Use a for loop

echo $my_array[$key+1];
echo $my_array[$key+2];
echo $my_array[$key+3];

echo $my_array[$key-1];
echo $my_array[$key-2];
echo $my_array[$key-3];
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!